# Mouse events propagation from marker to underlying map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have one question, 
why dose mouse events related to a map never fire when we are over marker

exp. having a mouse move listener added to a map is never called when we move over a marker
(there is not so called event propagation or bubbling).

This was actully working on maps v2!

Is it a bug, or its changed to this behavior in v3?

Blaze

Here is the example...

If you move around the map, the mapLabel is updated as should be
but if u move over the marker the mapLabel is never updated

```
var map;
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'MOUSEMOVE', function() {
    document.getElementByID('moveLabel').innerHtml = 'Mouse map move' + Math.random();
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'MOUSEOUT', function() {
    document.getElementByID('markerLabel').innerHtml = '';
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'MOUSEOVER', function() {
    document.getElementByID('markerLabel').innerHtml = 'Mouse over marker';
  });
}
```

Comment: Please show us your relevant code.

Comment: Hi Josh

there is nothing special in the code, I just add a map move listener and one marker to the map.

Comment: Hi Josh

there is nothing special in the code, I just add a map move listener and one marker to the map.
1. If the marker is set to clickable=false the map move event over the marker is fired but in this case all assign marker events are not fired!
2. If the marker clickable=true then all marker events are fired but the map move event over the marker never fires...

In V2 the map events wore always fired regardless on the fact you are over overlay or not.

Comment: No matter how simple, its best to show us what you've tried. It is less for us to guess and shows initiative on your part.

Answer (score 1):

All google maps' data that is drawn placed on 7 layers. These layers are called Panes. According to what pane the drawing belongs , it can receive or not receive events. For more information look at the [google.maps.MapPanes](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapPanes) documentation.

**UPDATE:** Google maps draws all data on 7 panes. All panes are children of the same parent. For event bubbling it is neccessary that the relation of elements should be `parent-child` ( then child can bubble the event to parent ),but not `sibling-sibling`. In `sibling-sibling` relation, event is received by element with the highest `z-index`. This is the reason you don't get events bubbled from marker's pane to map's pane.

Comment: If u check the MapPanes you will see that there are 6 panes, overlayImage(3th pane is the marker images layer) and this one gets events also..

Im not talking about this, I added a code above. Check it!
Tnx