# Enabling event propogation effectively in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, event-propagation

As covered in an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9620978/594137), I have a piece of code which (nice and simply) keeps a div updated with the current location of the cursor like so.

```
function updateLocation(e) {
    document.getElementById('current_coordinate').innerText = e.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
}
```

It works brilliantly until the cursor moves over an overlay. The overlay consumes the event so the event listener I have defined on the map never fires.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', updateLocation);
```

Questions:

1. Must I redefine that listener on every overlay I create or is there simpler way?
2. If I must define listeners on every overlay, roughly how many overlays may I have without performance suffering?

The overlay is interactive and so setting `clickable` to false is not an option.

Comment: I have answered to similar question in past.See->http://stackoverflow.com/a/10364661/1113426

Answer (score 0):

See also these discussions that indicate this is a bug - as yet unfixed:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/z_K7hxKhonI

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/mM0mB9FcyAU